# webpage is not fitting on mobile screens

Tags: html, css, asp.net

So I got a problem with fitting the webpage on mobile devices. On PC it works without single problem, but when I'm trying on mobile device it will not fit fully on screen but is somehow overflowing? It creates white space on right side. I'm using basic html/css and developing website with Asp.Net. But this is on 99% problem with html/css. What is important to say none of the content is overflowing the actual window size, it is only blank space.
[image: White space on right side]

On different setting it is not even fitting the header.
[image: Header not fitting and white space]

**html page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles/footer.css>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles/general_index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles/index_page.css">
</head>
 <body>
    <div class="background-container">
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**general_index.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FDF1E6;
    font-family: Outfit, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%; /* take full browser width */
    height: 100%;
}

.background-container {
    background-image: url("../background.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 650px;
}



body::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: adding `overflow: hidden;` to your body can show if it's an overflow problem or it's a problem with your dev tools zoom / resizing. Sometimes `ctrl` + `+` zoom in then clicking magnifying glass then reset, will fix zoom issues on your page. If it's an overflow issue it's probably a margin border or fixed width on some element in your page.

Comment: Maybe adding display: block; or width and height 100% would help on the ::before pseudo-element. Your body is a flexbox and ::before is its child, it will behave as a flex item. You've taken it out of the flow with position: absolute but maybe there is still some properties catching the flex train, you have to specify your CSS a bit more to avoid unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 0):

The issues might be the padding-bottom: 650px; that you are using.

Consider using a percentage or viewport-based height (vh) instead to ensure the issue is not reoccurring.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for tips. I found out that the problem was that in navbar a set position:absolute, but did not set the specifics(like right:0) and this was creating this weird behaviour. Really thank you for tips.